# SuiteScript AddButton not showing for other users

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I have created two buttons which show on an Estimate. One button shows to all, the other when a user has a set role.

```
form.addButton({id : 'button1', label : 'button1', functionName : "window.open('" + urlCallBack1 + "', '_blank')"});
var acceptedRoles = [ common.CONSTANTS.ROLES.TEAM_LEADER, 
common.CONSTANTS.ROLES.ADMINISTRATOR ];
if(acceptedRoles.indexOf(userRole) > -1)
{
    form.addButton({id : 'button2', label : 'button2', functionName : "window.open('" + urlCallBack2 + "', '_blank')"});
}
```

When I personally go to an Estimate logged in as either role I see the buttons. Any other role, I log into does not see button2. This is the expected behaviour.

However, when our users with the team leader role log in, they see button1 but can not see button2. The same script serves up both buttons so it's not a permissions issue on the script itself.

**EXPECTED BEHAVIOUR:** When a team leader logs in they can see button2 on an estimate.

**ACTUAL BEHAVIOUR:** When a team leader logs in they can not see button2 on an estimate.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried explicitly casting your 'userRole' variable to an integer value to ensure your condition is comparing two values of the same type? I.e below.

```
if(acceptedRoles.indexOf(parseInt(userRole)) > -1)
```

Comment: The problem is it works for my login. I will give this a try but if this was the error, it wouldn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Is your script deployment in Testing mode?  If so, that script will only execute for the script owner.  Likely you in this case.

Comment: Thanks for you input. No the script serves up two buttons. One of them shows, the other doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I think this has something to do with the value of userRole not matching any value in acceptedRoles array. Check the value of userRole and if it matches the constant value for TEAM_LEADER.

```
var acceptedRoles = [ 'TEAM_LEADER', 'ADMINISTRATOR' ];
var userRole = 'TEAM_LEADER';

 if(acceptedRoles.indexOf(userRole) > -1) { 
      console.log('here');
}
```